# How do I correct the shell script to recognize the newline character on another server running Linux?

Tags: shell, scripting, newline, sftp, ksh

The new-line character is correctly recognized on server2 (Solaris) while it is taken as a <kbd>backslash</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> character on server1 (Linux). How do I correct this?

While working on a simple script that accepts arguments and sends out mails I first noticed this rather odd behavior..

Syntax: `$ ksh SEND_MAIL.sh <to> <Subject> <body>`

1. Now when I run that script on server-1

   [kent@server1] $ ksh SEND_MAIL.sh name@site.com "Subject" "123\n456"
   [Thu Jan 10 10:51:18 EST 2013] - Starting to send mail to: name@site.com,
       with the subject \'>>>123\n456\'

   Notice that the new-line character is taken as backlash-n.
2. While on server-2 the `\n` special character correctly expands to a new-line character.

   [kent@server2] $ ksh SEND_MAIL.sh name@site.com "Subject" "123\n456"
   [Thu Jan 10 10:51:18 EST 2013] - Starting to send mail to: name@site.com,
       with the subject \'>>>123
   456\'

I think I may need to change some KornShell environment variables but I can not figure it out.

**UPDATE:**

After Henk's guidance below... I see that knowing the difference is not enough in helping me solve main issue - that is to have the script on server1 recognize the `\n` characters as a new-line. So I have improved my question.

---

### **Notes:**

> Server1 is a Linux server, while Server2 is Solaris.

---

**Environment details > KornShell:** - As suggested by *Henk Langeveld*

On server1:

```
[kent@server1]$ ksh --version
  version         sh (AT&T Research) 93t+ 2010-02-02
[kent@server1]$ echo ${.sh.version}
bash: ${.sh.version}: bad substitution
[kent@server1]$ [ "${ERRNO}" ] && echo ksh88 || echo ksh93
ksh93
[kent@server1]$ [ "`echo "\c" | grep c`" ] && echo ksh93 || echo ksh88 
ksh93
```

On server2:

```
# I'm am in bash
[kent@server2]$ ksh --version 
$
$ ksh --version
$ 
[kent@server2]$ echo ${.sh.version}
bash: ${.sh.version}: bad substitution
[kent@server2]$ [ "${ERRNO}" ] && echo ksh88 || echo ksh93
ksh93
[kent@server2]$ [ "`echo "\c" | grep c`" ] && echo ksh93 || echo ksh88 
ksh93
```

---

On server 1 & 2 I get the same *behavior*:

```
$ echo -e "1\n2"
1
2
$ echo "1\n2"
1\n2
$ echo $'1\n2'
1
2
```

---

**Code:**

SEND_MAIL.sh

```
#Syntax: $ ksh SEND_MAIL.sh <to> <Subject> <body>
TO_REC=$1
SUBJECT=$2
MESSAGE=$3
echo "$MESSAGE"| mailx -s "$SUBJECT" $TO_REC
```

---

Putting the line `set | grep SH` in the script on both the servers to check the shell it is running on as *Oliver* suggested below.

On server1:

```
[kent@server1]$ ksh SEND_MAIL.sh kent@123.com "Subject" ">>>123\n\n456$a"
KSH_VERSION=.sh.version
SHELL=/bin/bash
SHLVL=3
SSH_ASKPASS=/usr/libexec/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass
SSH_CLIENT='3.209.100.144 59645 22'
SSH_CONNECTION='3.209.100.144 59645 3.56.9.127 22'
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/1
...
```

On server2:

```
[kent@server2]$ ksh SEND_MAIL.sh kent@123.com "Subject" ">123\n\n456$a"
SHELL=/bin/ksh
SHLVL=1
SSH_CLIENT='3.209.100.144 49351 22'
SSH_CONNECTION='3.209.100.144 49351 3.56.29.159 22'
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/2
...
```

Comment: The script may have nothing to do with it. Do you have the same behaviour when passing your string to a simple unix command (like `echo`)?

Comment: larsmans - I added the code.
@Khaur - Pls see the 'behavior' section above.. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this AST ksh93, pdksh, or an older ksh88?

Here's how you can check the version of your `ksh` by checking the output of `ksh --version` and the value of `${.sh.version}`

```
$ ksh --version
version         sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-06-26
$ ksh -c 'echo ${.sh.version}'
Version AJM 93u+ 2012-06-26
```

Then tell us if the results are the same on the two servers. Older versions of ksh may actually report an error.

---

Solution for ksh93:

On server1, embed your \n in a ksh93 `Ansi string`, by enclosing it in `$'` and `'`:

```
two_lines=$'one\ntwo'  && print "$two_lines"
one
two
```

This will extrapolate any C-style escapes.

Comment: I updated my post with the outputs.. They both seem to be running the same version of korn shell.

Comment: Minor edit to assure that the echo ${.sh.version} is actually performed by ksh. Your servers run different shells, as explained in my follow-up answer. I tried to merge that in here, but that got messy. – 11 hours ago *fixed typo*

Comment: The problem with ANSI strings is that it would allow you to use UNIX variables inside them.. So how do I get the newline character and also have the UNIX variables to expand correctly ?

Comment: Hi Kent, create shell constants for the special characters using ANSI strings (`NL=$'\n'`).  Then concatenate all of them in a double quoted string ( `message="$line_one${NL}$line_two"` )

Comment: Thanks @Henk, I will do that. I appreciate your guidance with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

see, on each server:

- the version of ksh
- which shell you logged in when when trying: `grep kent /etc/passwd` will show the login shell in the last field).
- And do a `head -n 1 /path/to/SEND_MAIL.sh` to see if one or the other sports a different "shebang".
- And finally, put the line `set | grep SH` in another script, say `./test.sh`, and then `chmod +x ./test.sh` , and run it : `./test.sh` : to see if it is run with a different shell in each server

Comment: The shebang will make no difference: the scripts are being invoked explicitly using ksh. The shebang only makes a difference if you're executing a script directly.

Comment: Hi Olivier, the code is identical so shebang is not the issue.. Pls see my post, I have updated it with the output. 
Also `grep kent /etc/passwd` doesn't work as we are using LDAP so my account is not in /etc/passwd.. I am not too familiar with this..

Answer (score 2):

The two servers have different `ksh` binaries.  Server 1 is the most recent ksh93 from AT&T as bundled with most linux systems (debian and EL derivatives).  Server 2 is a maverick. Perhaps that's `pdksh`?  This explains the differences you're seeing.

On server1:

```
[kent@server1]$ ksh --version
  version         sh (AT&T Research) 93t+ 2010-02-02
```

On server2:

```
# I'm am in bash
[kent@server2]$ ksh --version 
$
```

Answer (score 0):

For korn shell on Linux, try print or printf instead of echo. That works for me. I am currently using it to port my scripts from AIX to Linux.I have not tested all possible contxts, but so far it has been working well. Another option, which I tried prior to this, which also works is this:

In some env setup file like .profile, add this statement:
export NL="
"
You should hit the ENTER key after typing " on the first line and hit " again on the very firts column on the new line.

Then replace all \n with ${NL}, the curly braces are required since you do not want what follows $NL to be treated as part of the env var name.

Good luck